# Unable to attach screen shot to cucumber JVM report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java, cucumber-junit

I am using the cucumber version 4 in my project I am using the following dependencies in my project.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>ABCXYZ</groupId>
<artifactId>ABCXYZ</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>ABCXYZ</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<build>
    
    <plugins>
    
    <!-- Plugin For Reporting  -->  
         <plugin>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.0</version>
            <executions>
            
                <execution>
                    <id>execution</id>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <projectName>ABCXYZ</projectName>
                        <!-- optional, per documentation set this to "true" to bypass generation of Cucumber Reports entirely, defaults to false if not specified -->
                        <skip>false</skip>
                        <!-- output directory for the generated report -->
                        <outputDirectory>target/cucumber-report-html</outputDirectory>
                        <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                        <inputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</inputDirectory>
                        <jsonFiles>
                            <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                            <param>**/*.json</param>
                        </jsonFiles>
                        <!-- optional, defaults to outputDirectory if not specified -->
                        <classificationDirectory>${project.build.directory}</classificationDirectory>
                        <classificationFiles>
                                <!-- supports wildcard or name pattern -->
                                <param>sample.properties</param>
                                <param>other.properties</param>
                        </classificationFiles>
                        <parallelTesting>false</parallelTesting>
                        <!-- optional, set true to group features by its Ids -->
                        <mergeFeaturesById>false</mergeFeaturesById>
                        <!-- optional, set true to get a final report with latest results of the same test from different test runs -->
                        <mergeFeaturesWithRetest>false</mergeFeaturesWithRetest>
                        <!-- optional, set true to fail build on test failures -->
                        <checkBuildResult>false</checkBuildResult>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    
    
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
      <configuration>
          <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
     </configuration>
     <dependencies>  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
                <artifactId>surefire-junit47</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        </dependency> 
    </dependencies>
    </plugin>
    
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </plugin>                  
    </plugins>      
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <reportSets>
                <reportSet>
                    <reports>
                        <report>index</report>
                        <report>license</report>
                        <report>project-team</report>
                        <report>distribution-management</report>
                        <report>dependancy-info</report>
                        <report>scm</report>
                        <report>issue-tracking</report>
                        <report>cim</report>
                        <report>summary</report>
                    </reports>
                    <configuration>
                        <linkonly>false</linkonly>
                    </configuration>
                </reportSet>
            </reportSets>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.gdal</groupId>
        <artifactId>gdal</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.1</version>
    </dependency>   

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-project</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugin-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-plugin-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.12</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-jvm-deps</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
         <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
         <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
         <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency> 
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.appium</groupId>
        <artifactId>java-client</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
         <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
         <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
         <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
         <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
         <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
         <version>4.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    

    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
       <version>1.7.5</version>
   </dependency>
  
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
       <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
       <version>1.6.4</version>
   </dependency>

   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Using above dependencies I am able to generate the 'Cucumber jvm report'.

Also I have written the code in java, for attaching the screen shot to report, I am taking screenshot only when the scenario get fail.

```
@After
public void CloseBrowser(Scenario scenario) {
    if (scenario.isFailed()) {
        System.out.println("Scenario is Failled Taking ScreenShot...!!!");
        TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
        byte[] screenshot = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
        scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
    }
}
```

I am not sure is there anything I am missing, but screen shot is not attaching to the report.
The default html report which is generated by cucumber is displaying the screen shot.

can some one please help me on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check the screenshot are embedded on the After Hooks steps on the html report?, This 5.3.0 version is attaching the screenshot at Hooks step as we have our logic in `@After` hooks. I also first struggled and later noticed this.

Comment: I have checked in target folder->index.html file, there i can see the screenshot but in cucumber-html-reports it is not attaching screen shot.

Comment: Please check once again. Open the cucumber-html-report file. Go to failed feature-failed testcase. Then you may see three sections Hooks-Steps-Hooks under that. Expand the last Hooks (that is actually @After hooks), here you will see the failed screenshot. I am seeing from my side with the same cucumber report jar version as you have.

Comment: Thanks, I can see it under @after hooks.

Comment: Great you can see it. If it solved your problem, please accept the answer.